# how to create a H2 database file that can be opened with SQL Workbench/J?

Tags: scala, h2, slick, sql-workbench-j

I am attempting to create a H2 database on file with slick, and open that file with SQL Workbench/J for further query processing. I am using the files below in a IntelliJ project, and it seems that it creates successfully a t.mv.db file and seemingly a M table. However after trying to connect to it in SQL Workbench/J I get these errors (going to investigate them now):

```
TABLE()

Syntax error in SQL statement "TABLE[*]()"; expected "TRUNCATE, {"; SQL statement:
TABLE() [42001-191] [SQL State=42001, DB Errorcode=42001]

SELECT * FROM M

Table "M" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM M [42102-191] [SQL State=42S02, DB Errorcode=42102]my
```

Could someone help me with how to create a durable H2 database file that can be opened with SQL Workbench/J?

main scala file:

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

final case class Message(sender:String, content:String)

final class MessageTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Message](tag, "M") {

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def sender = column[String]("sender")

  def content = column[String]("content")

  def * = (sender, content) <>(Message.tupled, Message.unapply)
}

object Curator {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    final case class Message(sender: String, content: String)
    val db = Database.forConfig("h2file")
    lazy val messages = TableQuery[MessageTable]
    Await.ready(db.run(messages.schema.create),2 seconds)
    db.close()
  }
}
```

my application.conf:

```
h2file = {
  connectionPool        = disabled
  url                   = "jdbc:h2:~/scala/workspace/Curator/t"
  driver                = "org.h2.Driver"
  keepAliveConnection = true
}
```

my build.sbt:

```
name := "Curator"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick"           % "3.1.0",
  "com.h2database"      % "h2"              % "1.4.185",
  "ch.qos.logback"      % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2"
)
```

SQL Workbench/J settings:

```
Driver: H2 Database Engine (org.h2.Driver)
URL: jdbc:h2:~/scala/workspace/Curator/t"
```

I also linked to a downloaded h2-latest.jar with "manage drivers"

Comment: Why don't you just use a `create table` from inside your program?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. You mean using SQL compatibility in Slick and write SQL? well, I believe that I can insert rows and retrieve them again in the scala-program, which leads me to believe that there is something in the interoperability between the generated database file and SQLWorkBenchJ.

Comment: SQL Workbench only uses the H2 driver to access the data. If it can't access it, the H2 database file is corrupt or not created correctly. You can verify this by writing a simple Java program that connects to the H2 database using JDBC.

Comment: so you suspect that my scala/slick-program, although it work generate a non-standard H2 database file?